# How to get server side events (onmessage) in C# in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, servicestack

Im not experienced at all with SSE (or web development in general) so please forgive my ignorance on display. Im trying to get `onmessage` events from an SSE stream in C# in Unity. I need this to run continuously (preferably async) as these events just keep coming.

For context I'm trying to get events from: https://www.blaseball.com/events/streamGameData

The behaviour I'm trying to replicate in Javascript is:

```
const evtSource = new EventSource(https://www.blaseball.com/events/streamGameData, {});
evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data)["value"];
    // Use data here
}
```

So far I have tried:

**Web Request**

I found some sample code on a Github jist that uses WebRequest (code below). This works, and gives me the right data back, but I dont understand how (if at all) I can only get the `onmessage` events, like the supplied JS, this way. Obviously this code just locks the application in its current state.

```
void Main()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    var buffer = new byte[2048];

    while(true)
    {
        if (!stream.CanRead)
            return;

        int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        if (length > 0) 
        {
            var text = encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
            // Parse...
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Stack**

I tried using the ServiceStack `ServerEventsClient` ([Link](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client)) to get events. I built the NuGet package in VSCode and placed the .netstandard2.0 builds in Unity's Plugins folder. The packages compile fine in Unity and I can access their APIs with no issue.

However, `await client.Connect()` never returns. I'll admit that I dont really understand these APIs. I used the code verbatim from the link above using `Using C# Async/Await friendly API’s` and I also tried with `client.Start()` for good measure. Nothing. However one line in the ServiceStack documentation suggests that this only works with ServiceStack servers? (I do not know enough about SSE to understand the difference)

```
async void Connect()
{
    var client = new ServerEventsClient("https://www.blaseball.com/events/streamGameData");
    client.OnMessage += (evt) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Message!");
    };
    client.Start();
    
    ServerEventConnect connectMsg = await client.Connect();
    // Never gets here...
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong with ServerStack, or if that route is even possible? Or perhaps help with a Web Request method? Recommendations for other methods or libraries are also very welcome...

Comment: I think you are after WebSocket or Socket.IO. Best is that you look them up, there are assets available in unity store with tutorials.

Comment: You can’t use ServiceStack’s SSE clients which are only opinionated for consuming [ServiceStack’s Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events)

Comment: @Everts SocketIO documentation suggests it only works with SocketIO servers and I was told that WebSocket and SSE are actually different technologies that cannot talk to each other?

For what its worth I tried WebSocket using WebSocketSharp and it wouldnt connect.

Comment: @Matt If your server type is not a must, I think Socket.IO can solve all your network communication problem.
FMWebSocket now supports all Unity3D Build, including WebGL and HTML. https://youtu.be/kfwc4BCASjs
This short demo shows you how easy it works and sending bytes or message in one line command.

and websocket can do live stream with ease too.
https://youtu.be/1zh3VkwhIag

Those are just examples with the use of socket.io.

Comment: @Matt do you find any solution for using "ServiceStack's SSE Client " in unity?